# In diagrams.net how to I use mm when customising the paper size?

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

Im using drawio / diagrams.net and are trying to map out a room where all the measurements for the room are in millimeters.

I started this by setting the units to mm so I could set the object sizes to the measurements however I tried to set the page size accordingly and notices that the only units available for customisation are inches. Is there a way to change this so I can update the page size as per my preferred unit

The diagram below shows where I tried to change the page sized.

[image]